# Given the transformation matrix, show that $f$ is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra

How does one determine if the assertion below is true or false?

Let $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ be the linear transformation with transformation matrix

$$A_f = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
It then follows that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Matrix has dimension 2. So it is surjective.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: the dimension of the matrix is 2 (as it has two linearly independent columns) and so the dimension of the image is 2.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part. What I don't understand is, why that implies surjectivity?

Comment: What is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is $2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not familiar with the basic theory about rank and linear mappings, you could proceed as follows:

For each $[b_1\quad b_2]^{\mathsf T}$, consider the equation 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\ b_2
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which clearly has a solution $[b_1 \quad b_2 \quad 0]$. Therefore for each $\boldsymbol b \in \mathbb R^2$, there exists some $\boldsymbol x \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $f(\boldsymbol x)=\boldsymbol b$, which implies $f$ is surjective by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix has two linearly *independent* columns and that means its image has dimension two...and we're done.

**Other way**: Choose any $\;\binom xy\in\Bbb R^2\;$ , then

$$A_f\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\0\end{pmatrix}=\binom xy$$

Comment: But I don't understand why two linearly independent columns implies surjectivity.

Comment: @Parseval  Then I can't help you with that one, as it is one of the most basic features of matrices as linear maps. Yet you still have the "other way" to prove what you want...

Answer (score 2):

@DonAntonio answers it perfectly but maybe you are confused with what you want. Let me elaborate on Don's answer. To show surjectivity we have to show that for every vector in image there exist a vector in domain which gets mapped to it. Now for vector $\binom xy$ in image space we have vector $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\0\end{pmatrix}$ in domain which gets mapped to it. And so every vector in image space is touched upon by the linear transformation $f$ and so it implies its surjectivity. Hope it helps.